# What applescript will a particular application accept?

Tags: macos, applescript

I see a lot of applications that can respond to applescript messages such as this one.

```
tell application "Safari"
    return URL of front document as string
end tell
```

How can I query an application to find out what commands it will accept?  Is there a tool for doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AppleScript Editor, do "Open Dictionary", select the application you are interested in, and you get a nice browser that shows the commands and their documentation (if the developers have chosen to provide any).