# In OSX can I use a system call to pass a command to a running terminal in a new tab?

Tags: macos, terminal, ipc

Specifically,

In OSX 10.6 from a system call, I want to open a file for editing with VIM in a preexisting terminal (i.e. Terminal.app) by opening a new tab.

Of course I can open a new instance of terminal

```
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -e vim MyFile
```

And, of course I can figure out the PID of the running instance of *Terminal* but I don't know how to pass a command into that running program. Or, if *Terminal* supports receiving commands and if it will open a new tab.

If someone knows how to do this with a similar system (e.g. linux and xterm) it could help me figure it out with OSX and Terminal - or, is there some other technique to prevent opening so many terminals instances?

**EDIT: CHEAP SOLUTION**

I created an AppleAcript script

```
on run app_arg
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Terminal"
            key code {55, 36}
            set frontmost to true
            key code {55, 17}
            keystroke item 1 of app_arg
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

and run it via the system call like so

```
/usr/bin/osascript NEWSCRIPT.scpt "args"
```

It's dirty but it gets the job done - thanks!

Comment: I would guess that it is pretty easy to do from Applescript ("Tell application Terminal to...", look at the dictionary for Terminal to see what language it accepts), o now you need to know how to run an aplescript. Not my field, but Stack Overflow might know... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091278/what-applescript-will-a-particular-application-accept

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870270/sending-commands-and-strings-to-terminal-app-with-applescript

Comment: @Rob: Yes it is, but in this case both the application in question and the answer are Mac specific. I think I'll nix the unix tag to make it better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to accomplish the is with applescript.  You can send applescript to things in OS X with the `osascript` command.  I wasn't able to find anything quickly that directly shows how to open a new tab with a command running in it, but I was able to find a couple of references to automating `Terminal.app` in various other ways with applescript, and I think they may point you in the right direction.

- [Various random Terminal.app applescript hacks mostly centered around changing colors](http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-2894.html).
- [An applescript hack that opens a new terminal window without creating a new Terminal process](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/?permalink=Terminal_tricks_8220_term_8221_and_8220_clone_8221.html).
- [A nice StackOverflow question about how to query an application to discover what applescript it supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091278/what-applescript-will-a-particular-application-accept) (stolen from a comment on your question by @dmckee)
- [And this nice StackOverflow question concerning Terminal.app's applescript specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870270/sending-commands-and-strings-to-terminal-app-with-applescript) (again stolen from a comment by @dmckee)
- [An even better exploration of the Leopard Terminal.app's applescript from Ruby no less](http://onrails.org/articles/2007/11/28/scripting-the-leopard-terminal)

And from that last link, it looks like the only way to do it is to use applescript to send the Command-T keystroke to the terminal.  That's ugly, but it'll work.  And then you can send the command you want to execute.  :-)

Comment: Damn! I just ran this down a few minutes late.

Comment: @dmckee, thanks for hunting down the SO links.  The external pages I link to have similar information, but the SO links present it much more nicely and have a bit more information.

Comment: @dmckee, I just used Google.  *grin* `apple terminal.app arguments` and then after scanning a few of those `terminal.app applescript`.

Comment: Alright - I worked up an answer using some info from these links. However, I wold have preferred not having to use AppleScript (can't always get what you want).

Comment: @bias, I'm sad it was so ugly.  It would be nice if it weren't, but I don't think pretty is possible here.

Answer (score -2):

There are three ways to do this:

- Use [`popen`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/popen.html)
- Use [`system`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/system.html)
- Use [`exec`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/exec.html) family

Comment: Can you please explain why the downvote when your question failed to highlight whether it was a programming language or not? Otherwise your question should be moved to superuser.com!

Comment: This isn't really responsive, because the OPs problem is he doesn't know what command he would use if typing it himself...

Comment: I didn't down vote you - I was reading your link on popen. I put it in stackoverflow since I don't think UNIX IPC qualifies as superuser tweeks and since this is code in a programming application.

Comment: I downvoted you because it doesn't answer the OPs question.  The OP doesn't need to know how to launch a new process, the OP needs to know how to get Terminal.app to create a new tab programatically.

Comment: No problem! :) @bias: Have you checked out the screen utility or is that available on Mac OSX? http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935

Comment: Understood - thanks Omnifarious for your input...no problem there...sorry if my answer is wrong.

Comment: Getting screen to create a new shell is different from getting Terminal.app to create a new tab. It might be as good a solution (or even better) but it is not what is requested.

Comment: I was thinking about how I could use screen, since that would be preferable. I'll have to look deeper into linux IPC itself and I'll likely need to use screen since I can't see how I can open a new tab in Terminal (and, to my google-ability, Terminal isn't extensively documented).